# Arcgis without WPF

Tags: c#, arcgis, esri

Hi im looking at Arcgis but the application is an embedded Labview app , we do link to a C# 4.5 DLL but   they dont support WPF.

Question can i use the arcgis DLL to just get a map as a bitmap ?

All we really need is the map and display coordinates of an object  , a proposed path ( between some way points) and calculate some sort of hitmap.

I know i can use the png files and load them as bitmaps and do it manually buit just loooking at how much i can use the API for.

Comment: why vote down with no comment seems a good question to me

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/). It doesn't require WPF.